# Migrate redmine to latest version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, redmine, bitnami

Im trying to migrate redmine to another server and update it to latest version.
I use bitnami stack for both machines, I installed clean latest version of redmine 4.1.1 on new and Im following official bitnami tutorial for migrate:
[Tutorial](https://docs.bitnami.com/ibm/apps/redmine/administration/upgrade/#upgrade-redmine-and-all-stack-components)

When I try to migrate db to the latest version with:

```
cd /opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/
sudo ruby bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get this:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `represent_boolean_as_integer=' for nil:NilClass
/opt/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/config/application.rb:60:in `<class:Application>'
/opt/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/config/application.rb:24:in `<module:RedmineApp>'
/opt/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/config/application.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/opt/redmine-4.1.1-8/apps/redmine/htdocs/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What is problem there ?

Comment: you likely need the correct rails version installed for your target redmine version: https://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/56459?r=56462

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. I understand you installed/deployed the latest version of the Bitnami Redmine solution and you are getting the error when running the db:migrate command in that new installation, correct? We suggest you check the Redmine's official guides to know if there is any extra step you need to apply before migrating the database. Please note that depending on the version you are migrating the application from, it may be extra steps to apply due to the previous version being to old.